# Is it possible to drive two PWM pins with opposite phase?

Tags: gpio, audio, electronics

One well-known trick to make a piezo buzzer sound louder is to actively drive both sides of it with an opposite phase: when pin 1 is at 0V, pin 2 is at 3.3V and vice versa. This creates a voltage swing of 3.3*2 = 6.6V, making the buzz [loud enough](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72178/increase-volume-of-piezo-buzzer) without any amplification.

How could I generate PWM signals of opposite phase using any of GPIO libraries? As a specific example, let's say I want to use GPIO pins 12 and 13 (PWM0/PWM1) at 50% duty cycle and a frequency of 1kHz.

Comment: The [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) and [lg](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/index.html) libraries both support this. If you provide a couple of GPIO and a frequency I can give concrete examples.

Comment: Why would you WANT to drive a piezo buzzer with PWM? They SHOULD be driven with a symmetrical signal to avoid DC. I have implemented differential drive on an Arduino, but you would get better results on the Pi using 5V - even better if you used a 5V differential drive.

Comment: @Milliways PWM is not a requirement of course, just something which can produce sound without keeping the software busy switching the pins. And I don't think DC is a problem: piezo buzzers are essentially ceramic capacitors optimized for noise level.

Comment: Would a hardware solution interest you?

Comment: @Seamus No, thanks, I know I can use a hardware inverter to get the signal of an opposite  phase.

Answer (score 3):

What sort of frequencies are you talking about?

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) can do this with waves (hardware timing).

E.g. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_wavePWM_py

My new [lg library](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/) can do this using software timed PWM.

E.g. Python http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html#tx_pwm

pigpio example using pigs (command line)

```
G1=12
G2=13
OFFSET=500
B1=$((1<<$G1))
B2=$((1<<$G2))
pigs m $G1 w
pigs m $G2 w
pigs wvag $B1 $B2 $OFFSET $B2 $B1 $OFFSET
pigs wvcre
pigs wvtxr 0
```

lgpio C example (local GPIO)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <lgpio.h>

/*
gcc -o lt1 lt1.c -llgpio
./lt1
*/

#define G1 12
#define G2 13

#define FREQ 1000
#define DUTY 50

#define ON_MICS (int)(1e6 / FREQ * DUTY / 100.0)

#define LFLAGS 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int h;

   h = lgGpiochipOpen(0);

   if (h < 0)
   {
      printf("gpiochip open failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   if (lgGpioClaimOutput(h, LFLAGS, G1, 0) != LG_OKAY)
   {
      printf("gpio claim output failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   if (lgGpioClaimOutput(h, LFLAGS, G2, 0) != LG_OKAY)
   {
      printf("gpio claim output failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   lgTxPwm(h, G1, FREQ, DUTY, 0, 0);
   lgTxPwm(h, G2, FREQ, DUTY, ON_MICS, 0);

   lguSleep(30);

   lgGpiochipClose(h);
}
```

rgpio C example (local and remote GPIO)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include <lgpio.h>
#include <rgpio.h>

/*
gcc -o rt1 rt1.c -lrgpio
./rt1
*/

#define G1 12
#define G2 13

#define FREQ 1000
#define DUTY 50

#define ON_MICS (int)(1e6 / FREQ * DUTY / 100.0)

#define LFLAGS 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sbc;
   int h;

   sbc = rgpiod_start(NULL, NULL);

   if (sbc < 0)
   {
      printf("connection failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   h = gpiochip_open(sbc, 0);

   if (h < 0)
   {
      printf("gpiochip open failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   if (gpio_claim_output(sbc, h, LFLAGS, G1, 0) != LG_OKAY)
   {
      printf("gpio claim output failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   if (gpio_claim_output(sbc, h, LFLAGS, G2, 0) != LG_OKAY)
   {
      printf("gpio claim output failed\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   tx_pwm(sbc, h, G1, FREQ, DUTY, 0, 0);
   tx_pwm(sbc, h, G2, FREQ, DUTY, ON_MICS, 0);

   lgu_sleep(30);

   gpiochip_close(sbc, h);

   rgpiod_stop(sbc);
}
```

lgpio Python module (local GPIO)

```python
import time
import lgpio as sbc

G1=12
G2=13

FREQ=1000
DUTY=50

ON_MICS = int(1e6 / FREQ * DUTY / 100.0)

h = sbc.gpiochip_open(0) # Pi's main gpiochip

sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, G1) # claim G1 of gpiochip
sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, G2) # claim G2 of gpiochip

sbc.tx_pwm(h, G1, FREQ, DUTY)
sbc.tx_pwm(h, G2, FREQ, DUTY, pulse_offset=ON_MICS)

time.sleep(30)
```

rgpio Python module (local and remote GPIO)

```python
import time
import rgpio

G1=12
G2=13

FREQ=1000
DUTY=50

ON_MICS = int(1e6 / FREQ * DUTY / 100.0)

sbc = rgpio.sbc()
if not sbc.connected:
   exit()

h = sbc.gpiochip_open(0) # Pi's main gpiochip

sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, G1) # claim G1 of gpiochip
sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, G2) # claim G2 of gpiochip

sbc.tx_pwm(h, G1, FREQ, DUTY)
sbc.tx_pwm(h, G2, FREQ, DUTY, pulse_offset=ON_MICS)

time.sleep(30)
```

Simplest method just sets one GPIO to active low.

```python
import time
import lgpio as sbc

G1=12
G2=13

FREQ=1000
DUTY=50

h = sbc.gpiochip_open(0) # Pi's main gpiochip

sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, G1) # claim G1 of gpiochip
sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, G2, lFlags=sbc.SET_ACTIVE_LOW) # claim G2 of gpiochip

sbc.tx_pwm(h, G1, FREQ, DUTY)
sbc.tx_pwm(h, G2, FREQ, DUTY)

time.sleep(30)
```